# Replit showing everything in the console as colours

Tags: python, replit

In Replit, when I make a Hello World program, everything looks like this:
A row of colours, displayed in the console
[image: A row of colours, displayed in the console]

But the code should just display "Hello World!"
[image: display "Hello World!"]

This seems to only happen on Firefox, my main browser, as on Chrome it works fine. I tried restarting Firefox, to no success. This issue also occurs on different projects, so it seems to be a browser problem.

Comment: I would suggest reporting this as a bug to repl.it at https://replit.com/support

Comment: Post it here: [https://ask.replit.com/](https://ask.replit.com/)